# HaxeFlixel: How to call a getter/setter variable in another class

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm building a basic game to learn the ins and outs of HaxeFlixel and want to call a variable with getter/setter properties from `MenuState` in the `PlayState`. Code looks something like this:

```
class MenuState extends FlxState
{
    @:isVar public var myVar(get, null):Bool;

    public function get_myVar():Bool
    {
      return myVar;
    }
}

class PlayState extends FlxState
{
    private var _foo:Bool;

    override public function create():Void
    {
        // var ms = new MenuState; doing it like this doesn't return anything
        _foo = MenuState.get_myVar();
        if (_foo)
        {
            // do this thing
        }
        else
        {
            // do that thing
        }
    }
}
```

With the ms variable it returns do that thing, without it I get an error `Class<MenuState> has no field get_myVar`. I'm sure that's probably not how to write the code, but at this point I'm just trying to get it to work. Essentially what I'm trying to do is get the MenuState to write a variable that the `PlayState` reads but can't write. How would I got about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myVar` and the getter function in `MenuState` are not [static](https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-static.html) in your code, so you cannot access them like `MenuState.get_myVar()`. I think making `myVar` static would be an ok solution to your problem.

You do not need to call `get_myVar()` directly. The getter will be called whenever you access `myVar` outside of `MenuState`. You can test that by adding a `trace("message");` to `get_myVar`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of it using a constructor function, i.e. `public function new()`. For this reason it's usually best to create a seperate class.hx for your var with a constructor function, then create an instance of it in playstate.

Otherwise, I would create a registry class to store vars that need to be shared, for example, create a new class called something like `Reg.hx` in your main package, then:

```
package;

//imports etc.

class Reg {

    public static var myVar:Bool;
}
```

then you just need to `import Reg` to any class you want and you can access it there. I like doing it like that anway!